# How pagination can be done in ruby on rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I heard that Pagination is included automatically for all controllers? How can it be implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more recent kaminari gem can be used in Rails 3.
You can refer
https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari

it is very simple to use.

Put this line in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'kaminari'
```

Then do bundle install

Typically, your controller code will look like this:

```
@users = User.order(:name).page params[:page]
```

On the views
Just call the paginate helper:

```
<%= paginate @users %>
```

Now you can see  the paginated result..

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there's nothing included automatically.  I believe there was built-in pagination in much earlier versions of Rails.

There are (at least) two gems that can be installed to do pagination.  The [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) gem has been around for years and can be used in Rails 2 or 3.  The more recent [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) gem can be used in Rails 3.

Answer (score 1):

As Don Roby said, there are several pagination gems and will_paginate and Kaminari are 2 popular ones. You can find some nice tutorial on pagination (incl. using these 2 gems) here : http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=pagination